# Error when testing filtering eager loaded data in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, eager-loading, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-bullet

Currently in my index action I load the data as:

```
posts.includes([:user, :status])
```

Note: Posts belongs to a user optionally. There are posts that have no user.

And then I'm filtering those posts based on different params.
Everything worked perfectly until I was trying to filter the posts that have no user.

```
scope :no_user, -> { where(user_id: nil) }
```

Theres is no error showing up when I try to test the behaviour in the browser but my controller tests (Minitest) are failing when the GET request is made with this particular filter.

```
Bullet::Notification::UnoptimizedQueryError
AVOID eager loading detected
  Post => [:user]
  Remove from your query: .includes([:user])
```

The funny part is when I remove the :user from the array, I get the exact opposite error on the other filter tests.

```
USE eager loading detected
  Post => [:user]
  Add to your query: .includes([:user])
```

Note: I get the same error if I try to use `left_outer_joins(:user)`

Is there a way to remove this error in tests without a conditional statement only for this particular filter?

Comment: This happens when you want associated data for conditional records, we experienced the same issue and fixed it using this gem
https://github.com/DmitryTsepelev/ar_lazy_preload

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix myself for the moment by just adding in `config/environments/test.rb` the following:

```
  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.add_safelist type: :unused_eager_loading, class_name: "Post", association: :user
  end
```